# Split a SVG word using multiple <text> elements rather than <tspan> ones

Tags: html, svg

Consider the following HTML5 inline `<svg>` sample for drawing a FOOBAR word (attributes omitted):

```
<svg>
  <text>
    <tspan>FOO</tspan>
    <tspan>BAR</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

I would like to get rid of those `<tspan>`s, replacing them with `<text>` blocks, like the following sample, **while keeping the same visual aspect (e.g. letter/syllable spacing) as before**:

```
<svg>
  <text>FOO</text>
  <text>BAR</text>
</svg>
```

(alternative way, if needed):

```
<svg>
  <g>
    <text>FOO</text>
    <text>BAR</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

How could I calculate the right placement of the `<text>` blocks (using Javascript) in this case?

**BONUS QUESTION:** How could I center this `<text>` group both horizontally and vertically within the `<svg>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## SVG Text

So getting text to display next to one another.
This is fairly simple:
Get the pixel length of the text with: `getComputedTextLength()` on a **text** element
And then setting the second **text** x attribute to that pixel length.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  //SVG document 
  var svgElem = document.getElementById("doc");
  //The first text element
  var text1 = svgElem.getElementById("text1");
  //The second text element
  var text2 = svgElem.getElementById("text2");
  //Setting the second texts attribute to text length of the first text.
  text2.setAttribute("x", text1.getComputedTextLength());
});
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.show {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="show">
  <h1>Javascript</h1>
  <svg id="doc" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="150">
    <text id="text1" x="0" y="50" font-size="25">FOO</text>
    <text id="text2" y="50" font-size="25">BAR</text>
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="show">
  <h1>Tspan</h1>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="150">
    <text y="50" font-size="25">
      TSP<tspan>AN</tspan>
    </text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

**Bonus question**? What is the bonus?
Anyways how to center.

Solution without viewBox property

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  //SVG document 
  var svgElem = document.getElementById("doc");
  //The text element
  var text1 = svgElem.getElementById("text1");
  var svgSize = svgElem.getBoundingClientRect();
  //Computing text height
  var textHeight = (svgSize.height/2)+text1.getAttribute("font-size")/2;
  text1.setAttribute("y", textHeight);
  //Computing text width
  var textWidth = (svgSize.width/2)-text1.getComputedTextLength()/2;
  text1.setAttribute("x", textWidth);
  
});
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.show {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="show">
  <h1>Javascript</h1>
  <svg id="doc" width="200" height="75">
    <text id="text1" x="0" y="0" font-size="20">FOOBAR</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Solution with viewBox property

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  //SVG document 
  var svgElem = document.getElementById("doc");
  //The text element
  var text1 = svgElem.getElementById("text1");
  //Gets the viewbox 4 properties [0, 0, 100 ,50]
  var svgVBox = svgElem.viewBox.baseVal;
  //Computing text height
  var textHeight = (svgVBox.height / 2) + (text1.getAttribute("font-size") / 2);
  text1.setAttribute("y", textHeight);
  //Computing text width
  var textWidth = (svgVBox.width / 2) - (text1.getComputedTextLength() / 2);
  text1.setAttribute("x", textWidth);
});
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.show {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="show">
  <h1>Javascript</h1>
  <svg id="doc" viewBox="0 0 100 50" width="200px">
    <text id="text1" x="0" y="0" font-size="20">FOOBAR</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I could get a slightly improved vertical alignment by using `text1.getBBox().height` combined with `text1.setAttribute("dominant-baseline", "text-after-edge")`, rather than `text1.getAttribute("font-size")`. Is it possible to get the same result without changing `dominant-baseline`?

Comment: @LaérciodeSousa you seem to know a lot more about text in svg then me. I have not used "dominat-baseline" before, but don't set an a fixed attribute in javascript just apply it to the svg element directly.